# Restrict can edit for the read SP group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions, modern-document-library

I would like to disable or grey out the "can edit" for the specific people in sharing options or read permission users. As this is creating confusing in files and folders.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you will be able to remove it using SharePoint out of the box functionalities based on read permissions.

Comment: Is there any other possibilities to hide that option, as of now I made default selection "Can View" but read permission users can change to "Can Edit" and share files so it can be edited. I want to restrict that.

Answer (score 0):

There is not out of box or direct way in SharePoint to achieve this.
This option is available only to users who are part of owners or admin groups. Remove users from these groups to restrict them from getting these options.
Where you are trying to fix this? At list/ library level permissions or list item or document level permissions?
You can create custom solution using Power Automate for access management.